# Repetitively executing a function in R when my input values are in a DataFrame?

Tags: r, dataframe, circlize

Working in R

myData is a DataFrame with 4 columns and B rows

X is a number from 1 to B

F is a function of D, E, F, and G

```
where D is myData[row X, col 1]
      E is myData[row X, col 2]
      F is myData[row X, col 3]
  and G is myData[row X, col 4]
```

How do I repetitively execute F for every value of X from 1 to B?

I have tried calling the columns in their entirety for D, E, F, and G but receive an error saying a logical value is missing. I am able to execute F for independently entered values for D, E, F, and G but doing so for my entire DataFrame is tediously time consuming.

Comment: Someone could likely help you quickly with this if you supply a short snippet of R code with a data.frame that looks like yours. Short of that, you would be best served looking at the help for `apply`

Comment: I think you want `Map(F, myData$col1[1:B], myData$col2[1:B], myData$col3[1:B], myData$col4[1:B])`

Comment: Or `purrr::pmap(unname(head(myData, B)), F) `

Comment: Or `do.call(Map, c(F, head(myData, B))) `.

Comment: Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper! I haven't explored the Map function yet so I'll try that.